# Function not reading a 2D array's [i][0] row

Tags: c++, arrays

Consider the following array :

```
arr[0][0] = 5.42; // val
arr[0][1] = (int)1;    // freq
arr[1][0] = 41.45;
arr[1][1] = (int)1; // freq
arr[2][0] = 10.55;
arr[2][1] = (int)1;// freq
arr[3][0] = 78.55;
arr[3][1] = (int)1;// freq
```

it is supposed to represent a (non cumulative) frequency table. so each value has a frequency of 1.

Now consider the following function :

```
      const int SIZE = 1;
    double standardDeviation(double list[][SIZE], double mean, int size) {
    double sumSquared = NULL;
    double sum = NULL;
    double sumFx = NULL;
    int sumFreq = NULL;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        sumFreq += list[i][1]; 

    return sumFreq;
    }
```

(obviously there's some code missing) 
but in the present code, my objective is to returned the sum of the frequencies, which should be 4, but it's returning values only from members of the array with index [i][0] - basically, the values.

Any ideas why?

Comment: What's up with the `(int)` typecasts?  `1` already *is* an `int`, and it's still going to get converted into a `double` when it goes in the array.

Comment: just a visual reminder to myself that it's the frequency line lol

Answer (score 2):

Your array isn't being accessed correctly, since you have:

```
const int SIZE = 1;
```

You need that to be:

```
const int SIZE = 2;
```

As an aside, none of these initializations make sense:

```
double sumSquared = NULL;
double sum = NULL;
double sumFx = NULL;
int sumFreq = NULL;
```

`NULL` is `0`, yes, but semantically it's intended to be used to indicate a null pointer, and none of those variables are pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter is declared as `double list[][1]`.

So `list[i][1]` is out of bounds.